# Quality of Sybase ASE support in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, delphi-2007, sap-ase

I have Delphi Professional 2007 and 2009 and was thinking of upgrading either or both to Enterprise due to a new project that requires me to interface to a Sybase ASE database.

I did some research and it appears that 2007 Sybase driver leaked memory and it doesn't appear that this problem was fixed.

Does anyone know if the Codegear Enterprise drivers for Sybase ASE are reliable and do any alternatives exist?

Answer (score 2):

The BDE had some huge shortcomings and it seems that a lot of those were brought right into DBExpress. Some of these include:

- No suport for multiple result sets
- No way to get your hands on server messages that are not errors
- No control over where the cursors are located
- No support for async calls (where you use ct_poll)

My advice would be to write your own (simpler than it sounds) or to use ADO. ADO exposes a lot of ASE's functionality and the performance is very good.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [NativeDB](http://www.nativedb.com/)? The website might be a little off-putting, but I have a legacy D5 app that connects to ASA using their tools. At some point in the next month or two I'm going to have to buy an upgrade so that I have their latest D2007 driver, because I need to move that legacy app to D2007.

It works well (and it's damn fast) with ASA - I don't know about ASE but it might be worth a quick email asking them, or downloading a trial component. It's not that expensive for what it does, either.